# How to clone using git and chain git config user.name

Tags: git, shell, version-control, terminal, chaining

I want to do command chaining with git. I want exactly to clone a repo then set the configurations for that working copy changing user.name, user.email.

I tried this:

```
git clone https://repoUrl.git && git config user.name "Khaled" && git config user.email "test@server.com"
```

But I got this error:

```
error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `git clone` puts its clone into a new directory by default. You must then `cd` into the directory before doing additional operations on the new clone.

Comment: Thanks. That right. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @torek comment this problem was fixed. `git clone` really puts its clone into a new directory and I needed to cd into it before calling the configs so here is the fixed version:

```
git clone https://repoUrl.git customDirectory && cd customDirectory && git config user.name "Khaled" && git config user.email "test@mail.com"
```

Answer (score 9):

```
git clone --config key1=value1 --config key2=value2 https://git.com/repo.git
```

Please reference: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Answer (score 2):

You have not in gitdir folder after clone please follow .

```
1) git clone https://repoUrl.git
```

now you need to enter in repo dir

```
2) cd gitfolder

3) git config user.name "Khaled" && git config user.email "test@server.com"
```

Comment: It is about chaining the commands in one line. You did them on separate commands.

Comment: add line && cd gitfolder in cmd

Answer (score 1):

try using this it worked for me:-

```
git clone https://github.com/rtyley/small-test-repo.git && git config --global user.name "name" && git config --global user.email "xxxxxxx@gmail.com"
```